# jQuery animate on ID change

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a toggle style menu with animate(). The menu shows up but it doesn't hide again. Here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/eenpK/2/

```
$("#menu2").on("click", function(){
$("#menu").animate({width: "200px"});
$("#menu2").attr("id", "menu2b");
});

$("#menub").on("click", function(){
$("#menu").animate({width: "-200px"}).css("overflow", "visible");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are changing `id` of elements, syntax `$(element).on("click","sub-element",function())` will work.

You are not changing `id` when `#menu2b` is clicked.

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu2", function () {
    $("#menu").animate({
        width: "200px"
    });
    $("#menu2").attr("id", "menu2b");
});

$(document).on("click", "#menu2b", function () {
    $("#menu").animate({
        width: "-200px"
    }).css("overflow", "visible");
    $("#menu2b").attr("id", "menu2");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eenpK/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Element `id`s should generally not change, and a toggle is not a good reason to do so. I would do something like this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/j2a4D/

```
$("#menu2").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).is('.expanded')) {
        $("#menu").animate({
            width: "-200px"
        }).css("overflow", "visible");
    } else {
        $("#menu").animate({
            width: "200px"
        });
    }
    $("#menu2").toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

For the sake of completeness, your fiddle isn't working for 2 reasons: `#menub` != `#menu2b`, and you are binding handlers to elements and expecting changes to those elements to change which handlers are bound to them (which doesn't happen).